# Javascript code to hide/display a given element when clicking an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Is it possible click the same link to hide and display coy below? This is what I have so far. I was able to create a javascript to display copy but I couldn't figure out how to click the same link to hide it. I have basic knowledge of html. This is the code that I am using

```
<p>
    <strong>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('text1').style.display='block';">
            Gifts that Don't Impact your Lifestyle
        </a>
    </strong>
    <div id="text1" style="display: none; margin-top: 2px;">
        There are many ways to give a gift to without impacting your lifestyle.
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('text2').style.display='block';">
            Gifts that Increase your Income
        </a>
    </strong>
</p>
<div id="text2" style="display: none;">
    You can enhance your income while supporting a Charitable Gift Annuity or Charitable Remainder Trust.
</div>
<p>
    <strong>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('text3').style.display='block';">
            Gifts that Provide for your Heirs
        </a>
    </strong>
    <div id="text3" style="display: none;">
        You can pass assets to your family on a tax favorable basis while providing immediate support.
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Please show your javascript code. We need to see the source, not the final displayed result. I don't see a link here...

Comment: You cannot place a `<div>` (block element) inside of a `<p>` (inline element) - reference http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
<p><strong><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('text1').style.display === 'block' ? document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'none': document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'block';">Gifts that Don't Impact your Lifestyle</a></strong></p><div id="text1" style="display:none; margin-top:2px;">There are many ways to give a gift to without impacting your lifestyle.</div>

<p><strong><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('text2').style.display === 'block' ? document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'none': document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'block'">Gifts that Increase your Income</a></strong></p><div id="text2" style="display:none;">You can enhance your income while supporting a Charitable Gift Annuity or Charitable Remainder Trust.</div>

<p><strong><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('text3').style.display === 'block' ? document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'none': document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'block'">Gifts that Provide for your Heirs</a></strong>
<div id="text3" style="display:none;">You can pass assets to your family on a tax favorable basis while providing immediate support.</div></p>
```

Comment: You should add your fiddle to the answer instead of posting it as a comment.  Also - you should provide the OP with an explanation as to why and how this works, instead of just the corrected code.  This provides a greater benefit to future visitors of this question and provides an opportunity for the OP to learn as well, so they don't post future questions expecting us to just fix their code for them.

Comment: This code is hard to maintain. On any modification you have to update two places of code. Should not teach bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using JQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#text1').toggle();">Gifts that Don't Impact your Lifestyle</a>
```

Comment: Why would we add jQuery for such a simple problem?  The OP didn't ask for a jQuery solution, and technically if you add 9,000+ lines of code to your project by adding the jQuery library, then it isn't a shorter solution.  I love jQuery, and it definitely has its purpose, but I think that far too often people rely on it for very simple tasks instead of taking the time to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate function to handle click event

```js
function toggle(div) {
  if ('block' == div.style.display)
    div.style.display = "none";
  else
    div.style.display = "block";

  return false;
}
```

```html
<p>
<strong>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return toggle(document.getElementById('text1'))">
    Gifts that Don't Impact your Lifestyle
  </a>
</strong>
<div id="text1" style="display: none; margin-top: 2px;">
  There are many ways to give a gift to without impacting your lifestyle.
</div>
</p>
<p>
<strong>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return toggle(document.getElementById('text2'))">
    Gifts that Increase your Income
  </a>
</strong>
</p>
<div id="text2" style="display: none;">
  You can enhance your income while supporting a Charitable Gift Annuity or Charitable Remainder Trust.
</div>
<p>
<strong>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return toggle(document.getElementById('text3'))">
    Gifts that Provide for your Heirs
  </a>
</strong>
<div id="text3" style="display: none;">
  You can pass assets to your family on a tax favorable basis while providing immediate support.
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Strictly using your html style

### Your html

```
<p><strong><a class="toggleSubText" href="#">Gifts that Don't Impact your Lifestyle</a></strong><div style="margin-top:2px;display:none">There are many ways to give a gift to without impacting your lifestyle.</div></p>

<p><strong><a href="#" class="toggleSubText">Gifts that Increase your Income</a></strong></p><div id="text2" style="display:none;">You can enhance your income while supporting a Charitable Gift Annuity or Charitable Remainder Trust.</div>

<p><strong><a href="#" class="toggleSubText">Gifts that Provide for your Heirs</a></strong><div id="text3" style="display:none;">You can pass assets to your family on a tax favorable basis while providing immediate support.</div></p>
```

### The JS

```
function toggleDisplay( event ){
   var sub = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling;
   sub.style.display = sub.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
   return false;
}


var ankersForSubText = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleSubText");

Array.prototype.filter.call(ankersForSubText, function(testElement){
   testElement.addEventListener("click", toggleDisplay, false);;
});
```

[Codepen for test](http://codepen.io/krettis/full/mypmKx/)

Personally, I would do the html this way:

```
<div class="toggleSubText>
   <a href="#">Gifts that Don't Impact your Lifestyle</a>
   <span class='subtext'>There are many ways to give a gift to without impacting your lifestyle.</span>
</div>
```